# Windows Insert File Path

Tags: files-and-directories

Suppose I want to Save["filename", foo] under Windows. Ordinarily, the way to deal with file names under windows is to open the Insert dialogue and find a file path, but in this use case, the file is new, so it does not exist (yet). Unlike every other windows program I am familiar with, Mathematica is unwilling to create a new file (that is, once you locate the relevant  folder, you type  in "mynewfile.m", Mma balks. This seems like a bug (sorry, Dan Lichtblau, a misfeature :)), but is there any reasonable workaround? Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Insert ▶ File Path... only inserts a string that represents the location of a file in the correct formating for your operation system. I also often misuse it to specify a filenames inside functions like `Save`. In that case I just select any file in the proper folder, and than change the last part of the string to the filename and extension I really want.

You can get a much more convenient and Windows like behavior using

```
Save[SystemDialogInput["FileSave"], foo]
```

This also works beautifuly with [`Export`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Export.html?q=Export), which is more suitable than [`Save`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Save.html?q=Save) in most cases, and can be made even more practical by predefining a file path (second input to [`SystemDialogInput`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SystemDialogInput.html))

```
Export[SystemDialogInput["FileSave", NotebookDirectory[]], foo]
```

---

In notebooks that I use regularly, but with different input and output files, I like to have multiple [`FileNameSetter`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FileNameSetter.html?q=FileNameSetter) at the beginning of the notebook.
E.g.

```
Row[{FileNameSetter[Dynamic[fooFile], "Save"], 
     "   File, in which the results are saved   ", Dynamic[fooFile]}]
```

> [image: fooSetter]

and than later in the program

```
Export[fooFile, foo]
```

Clicking on the Browse... button will bring up the Windows typical Save as dialog window and allows you to specify a filename, that does not jet exist in the usual way. The file itself will be created, when the `Export` function is evaluated.

Comment: Truly, you are wise, thanks!